# Альтернатива $_SESSION

Tags: сессия, php

С чего начиналось: [алтернатива кукисам](http://habrahabr.ru/blogs/javascript/29293/).

Можно ли на сервере воспользоваться какими-либо другими способами, помимо стандартного $_SESSION.

Критерием ответов должны стать следующие правила:

1. Не использовать базу данных (ни реляционную, ни nosql);
2. Не использовать, по возможности, файлы на диске (хочется избавиться от I/O для данной задачи);
3. Не использовать хранилища на клиенте

P.S.: По 2-му пункту я конечно погорячился. Но как сократить операции ввода/вывода или ускорить этот процесс до максимума? Хочется, чтобы отклик был максимально быстрым.

Answer (score 5):

Memcached :-)
Удовлетворяет всем пунктам

Comment: Правда ответ не удовлетворяет второму пункту. Плюсую пока.

Comment: @org, все данные memcached хранит исключительно в памяти

Answer (score 3):

Это, конечно, странное у вас желание, но если сильно хочется, то можно реализовать своё простенькое key/value хранилище в shared memory.

Для чего вам пригодятся функции [shmop_*](http://php.net/manual/en/book.shmop.php).